# how to make a web-gallery with RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

Im a newbie RoR kid, and I'm trying to make a web gallery app just like the onyx http://www.hulihanapplications.com/projects/onyx since it's outdated and i couldn't get it to work with my 2.3.8 rails' version.
So, are plugins like paperclip or carrierwave any good for me to start with. Or should i take another route and writh the app from scratch.

please provide me with good links regarding the subject.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paperclip is good way to start when it comes to any kind of images you'll add during runtime. You do have to install ImageMagick to change images into various sizes (thumbnails, etc), and it wouldn't be taking very long to create a webgallery with it (took me a day to figure it out).

http://www.cordinc.com/blog/2009/04/multiple-attachments-with-vali.html